# Syntactic Tree help

Tags: syntax, syntax-trees, adjuncts

Draw the syntactic tree for the deputy’s recent discovery of incriminating evidence; for full
credit, you must put all specifiers, all complements, and all adjuncts in triangles
& 
Draw the s-structure tree for Which pudgy pig did the shaggy sheep bite behind the barn?
For full credit, you must suppress the structures of all specifiers and all adjuncts.

Comment: Try here: http://eztreesee.coli.uni-saarland.de/